# Where is the Widget menu in Kit Kat?

Tags: app-widgets

I've got a Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.4 and I've downloaded a few Widgets, but if I open up the main app menu, I have no Widgets tab at the top and cannot find them.

I've tried rebooting, as recommended in the description on the play store but that didn't fix it.

Google seems to only offer app-specific advice and I can't find anything for [the one I'm most interested in](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitcreativ.autorotatewidget).

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is off-topic for SU, so I've voted to migrate it to the Android SE site. Having said that - go to your home screen and hit the menu button on your device, it'll pop up a Wallpapers, Widgets and Themes menu.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks! I had no idea there was an Android specific SE, but I guess I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out; I forgot you can hold down on a blank spot on the 'desktop' and it'll pull up a new screen for Widgets, Wallpapers, or Settings. I was able to access it there.

Comment: Also IIRC pressing or long pressing the menu/recent apps button will also bring up this menu and allow you to add widgets. I don't have nexus to hand at the moment but it works on the HTC / Samsung Google Edition devices.